# Interpolating orthodrome between two (lon,lat) points in Python?

Tags: python, great-circle

I have a polygon that consists of a few `(lon, lat)` points, each pair of consequent points is considered to be connected by orthodromes. I want to interpolate the polygon with some extra points between each source point pair (add some more waypoints lying on the orthodrome).

I know, that `geopy`, for example, has the possibility to calculate the distance on great circle, but I need some more: to find the waypoints on great circle.

I need something like that:

```
src_lon = 10
src_lat = 40

dst_lon = 20
dst_lat = 60

n_points = 100

lons, lats = interpolate_orthodrome(src_lon, src_lat, dst_lon, dst_lat, n_points)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a good solution:

`pyproj.Geod.npts`:

```
from pyproj import Geod


lon0, lat0 = 10, 10
lon1, lat1 = 20, 20
n_extra_points = 100    

geoid = Geod(ellps="WGS84")
extra_points = geoid.npts(lon0, lat0, lon1, lat1, n_extra_points)
```

- List item